# Set onclick events on textview created programmatically

Tags: android, click, textview

I create clickable textview dynamically depending on the records retrieved from the database just like this.

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllProfiles();
if(c.moveToFirst())
{
    do{
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(c.getString(1));
        tv.setTextSize(18);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv.setClickable(true);
        tv.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        mainLayout.addView(tv);

        tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tv.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }while(c.moveToNext());
}
else
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Profiles", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
db.close();
```

How can I set click events on each texview independently? On the way I see it, if I create a click event on the loop, the click event might get triggered by all textviews.

*Update tried adding events in every loop but got this error:

> "cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method".

Comment: Nop the event won't trigger on all TVs. I dont think so... have u tried?

Comment: tried it. see my updated post.

Comment: answered a way around for cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method".... TO me rest all OK... you can do in loop...good to go :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change your code as to add OnClickListener to TextView

```
TextView tv;
     if(c.moveToFirst())
            {
                do{
                    tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText(c.getString(1));
                    tv.setTextSize(18);
                    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    tv.setClickable(true);
                    tv.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                    tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // do you work here
                     }
                    });
                    mainLayout.addView(tv);

                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: see my edit answer just move `TextView tv` at class level means declare it as class level variable before onCreate in your Activity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have already done this one, But what i want is, need to set the background image different in each textview in a loop. So please let me know how can i do this one.

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
do{
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(c.getString(1));
                tv.setTextSize(18);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setClickable(true);
                tv.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tv.setId(1)
                tv.setOnClickListner(this);
                mainLayout.addView(tv);

            }while(c.moveToNext());
```

and put a onClick method as below

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.getId()==1)
    {

        // do stuf here
    }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't the id have to be a positive integer?

Comment: can you elaborate your answer? how can I process the onlick events usign their ids?

Comment: @SanketKachhela : `tv.setId(1)` must be dynamic if we use this then all textview created with same id

Comment: `tv.setId(1)` should be `tv.setId(any_id_counter)`

Answer (score 1):

use by this way...

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {

                        public void onClick(View voew) 
                        {
                             TableRow t = (TableRow) voew; //Your Layout
                              TextView firstTextView = (TextView) t.getChildAt(0);
                              String firstText = firstTextView.getText().toString();
                         }
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

**On the way I see it, if I create a click event on the loop, the click event might get triggered by all textviews.**

=> How is that possible? FYI, click evnet code will be fired if and only if click action is triggered. so assign `setOnClickListener` as usual you can assign.

```
do {
 tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
  });
} while(c.moveToNext())
```

Comment: Thank you! Learned a lesson today, try first before assuming.

Answer (score 0):

if rest all ok than u should

Try this

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ((TextView)v).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Hope it help

Comment: Thank you for giving a code to display the textview's text within a onlick. It works!

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K provided the answer first and properly. But you really helped me in displaying the text. Thanks!